# Including "Appendix" in ref / ref as in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, ref, appendix

I am using the `appendix` package with the `title` and `titletoc` options. This gives me an "Appendix" prefix in the TOC and in the actual section header. Is there an option to include the prefix in a `hyperref` `\ref` as well?

`\autoref` is out of the picture, since i dont like the "section" prefix for any other heading.

Alternative wording: Is there a way to print a `\ref` exactly as in the TOC?

Edit:

Here is a minimal source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\ref{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section one}\label{section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix one}\label{appendix}
\end{appendices}


\fullref{section} \\
\fullref{appendix}

\end{document}
```

and here is the result:
[image]

The last line should read `Appendix A Appendix one`, without the second to last starting with `Section`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe with `cleveref` (to be loaded after `hyperref`)?

Comment: You can update what `\autoref` prints. Perhaps you can give a complete, minimal example that replicates your current behaviour. That way we can help you much faster. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: Thank you! I am not too sure about `cleverref` since I am quite new to latex. Doesn't it work similar to hyperref?
I searched for a solution yesterday, and the closest to working was just deleting all `\*name` (e.g. `\sectionname`) macros, but I am not sure about the consequences here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (re)define the prefix used by `\autoref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\ref{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section one}\label{section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix one}\label{appendix}
\end{appendices}


\fullref{section} \par
\fullref{appendix}

% Define correct prefix used by references inside appendices
\newcommand{\Appendixautorefname}{Appendix}%

\autoref{appendix}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to avoid `Section` being inserted for all `\section` references, yet still have an `Appendix` prefix for `\autoref`erences pointing to the appendix, you can use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}[1]{}
\newcommand{\Appendixautorefname}{Appendix}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section one}\label{section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix one}\label{appendix}
\end{appendices}

\fullref{section} \par
\fullref{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know that, the problem is that i am using `\fullref` to link within my document and want to prefix a link to an appendix with "appendix", but not a section with "section". Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @thinegen: I've added something at the bottom of my answer that might address your concern.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to come back here. I ended up using the `fullref`command, put in `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}` and used `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Appendix \Alph{subsection}}` to have the word in front. Thank you for your help!